# In Dockerfile is it necessary to set publish mode to linux?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, publish

I've the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.207 AS dotnet-builder

WORKDIR /workdir
COPY ./ .
RUN dotnet restore "/workdir/Application.Host/Application.Host.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "/workdir/Application.Host/Application.Host.csproj" -c Release -o /workdir/Application.Host/out 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2.8
WORKDIR /workdir
COPY --from=dotnet-builder /workdir/Application.Host/Application.Host/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.Host.dll"]
```

My container run on the `linux` machine. In `Dockerfile` is it necessary to set publish mode to `linux` or not? for example:

```
dotnet publish "/workdir/Application.Host/Application.Host.csproj" --os linux --arch x64 -c Release -o /workdir/Application.Host/out
```

Does it affect on the performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Framework Dependent Deployement** (for example *something.DLL*) it is not required to specify OS.

If you are using **Framework Dependent Executable**, (for example *something.exe*) you can specify OS by using `-r` switch as below:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained false
```

Note the `--self-contained` swith which is set to `false`.

If you are using **Self Contained Deployement**, you can use `dotnet publish` as below:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained true
```

Where `-t` is an identifier (RID) to specify the target platform. Also note the `--self-contained` swith which is set to `true`.

Note: It is recommended to update your app to use newer version of ASP.NET Core.

Read more about `dotnet publish` command here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli